# Different return value for same parameters

Tags: function, grails

My grails application imports data from csv files in the database. Each file contains informations about offices and their turnover achieved in a given month
the parameters entered by the user

- file location
- a single airline to import
- period
- cooperation

The user can select a single airline (import a single file) otherwise, if the field is left blank, ie it will import all airline that are in this location

During file reading each line by line ,there is a call to a function in a service used to find the correspondence between an office and an agency.

**Problem:**

If the user chooses to import a single airline ( params.air != null), the function returns a true value,
but if he left empty fields airline and he choose to import all the files, the function always returns null

Controller :

```
if (params.air=="null")
{
    air = Airlines.list()
}
else
{
    air = Airlines.get(params.air)
}
def period = Period.get(params.per)
def coo_file = Cooperation.get(params.coo)
air.each
{
    def selected_airline = it
     // search csv_file for airline selected_airline
      ....
     // read csv_file
     cvs_file.toCsvReader(['separatorChar':';']).eachLine { tokens ->
                count_tokens++
 ....
def test_buro = fs.get_valid_buro(tokens[pos_iata],coo_file,period)
println(test_buro)
     }
}
```

Service:

```
//function
 Buro get_valid_buro(String agt,Cooperation coo,Period per)
{
 Date per_end = per.end_date
 Boolean found = false
 Buro selected =null
def sql_query = "SELECT b.id FROM Buro as b,Buro_agency as ba, Agency as a  WHERE b.id = ba.buro AND ba.agency = a.id  AND a.id = "+Agency.findByNumber_agency(agt)
   def data_sql = Data.executeQuery(sql_query)
    def bur_serv = []
    for(int i=0;i<data_sql.size(); i++)
    {
        bur_serv.add(Buro.get(data_sql[i]))
    }
  bur_serv.each{

        Date open_date = it.open_date_buro
        Date close_date = it.close_date_buro
        Cooperation bur_coo = it.cooperation
        if((bur_coo == coo && open_date <= per_end )&&(close_date>=per_end|| close_date==null))
        {
            found=true
            selected = it
        }
      }
```

I debug the application by putting a breakpoint in the bur_serv loop when it reaches the loop if ((bur_coo == coo && open_date <= per )&&(close_date>=per|| close_date==null)) it passes to the next iteration even though the condition is true!

what is wrong?!

Comment: couldn't the `get_valid_buro` method not be written in one single SQL statement?  also don't concat strings in your SQL.  executeQuery allows positional and named parameters to be passed.  what do you mean by "it comes out even though the condition is true"?

Comment: the condition in the if((bur_coo == coo && open_date <= per )&&(close_date>=per|| close_date==null)) is true but it is considered as false and it passes to the next iteration

Comment: it can not be true and false at once. how do you determine that?  have you added log statements?  or do you deduct this from your debugger? have you overridden the comparsion operators for comparing a `Date` with your `Period` domain object, or are those different `Period` types?

Comment: I deduce this from debugging, Period and date have the same type (Date).
but what really puzzles me I executed the program once by choosing a single airline everything works well, the second time I put this this  airline only in directory(file location) and let the  airline fields empty , the function always returns a value null

Comment: please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry for anything not clear but really it is a perplexing problem

Comment: my guess is, that your debugger shows a toString of the per object reassambling a date and the actual code comparing a real date with the per object can not work as it stands.

Comment: in fact I minimized the function code, I edited above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the tests that I realized I find that the problem is the comparison between two  domain class objects  of type "Cooperation".

when I test the condition

> if (bur_coo == coo)

it always returns false even both are the same value (have the same id).

I googled how to compare two domain class I find the operator "equals",  I modified the code

```
if (bur coo.equals (coo))
{
     println("true")
}
else
{ 
     println("false")
}
```

The result is always false.

**Solution**
The solution I found is to compare their id with

> if (bur_coo.id == coo.id)